# How to select from DataTable with join to same table?

Tags: c#, datatable

I have `DataTable` object, which holds some "tree data structure". Data is not stored in any database, I just use DataTable to manipulate data without SQL server.

My data looks like this (indents are only for better reading here):

```
DataTable dtCategories = GetCategoriesAsDataTable();

id    name    parentId
int   string  int
----------------------
 1    One         0
 2      OneA      1
 3      OneB      1
 4    Two         0
 5      TwoA      4
 6      TwoB      4
 7        TwoAA   5
 8        TwoAB   5
```

So far - I was thinking about selecting first level with "where parentId = 0" and putting this to separate DataTable, like this:

```
DataTable dtFirstLevel = dtCategories.Select("[parentId] = 0");

// and after this - create DataTable for second level
// but I don't know how can I use "IN" clause here
DataTable dtSecondLevel = dtCategories.Select(?????????);
```

1. How can I select only first 2 levels of tree?
2. How can I select this without SQL server (by using only data objects)?

Comment: What have you tried so far? How exactly do you determine the level of the tree?

Unless you have a defined relationship between your data and its level in the row (i.e. indents or A [1] versus AA [1-1] versus AAB[1-1-2]) using that select property is worthless to you because there's no way to traverse a tree. Why are you trying to model a tree structure with a DataTable, anyhow? Doing so with SQL might not be a problem, but it's pretty complicated without things like a WHERE clause.

Comment: I just added "what I tried so far", I think now you can figure out how to determine level of the tree.

Comment: would `foreach (var dt in dtFirstLevel){ var secondLevel = dtCategories.Select(string.Format("[parentId] = {0}", dt.Id));` work?

Comment: @DrewCopenhaver So I have to select first level (where parentId=0) and iterate to get rows, where parentId matches?

Comment: Shouldn't `TwoA` and `TwoB` have `4` as parentId?

Comment: @Default I think this will work, but I thought I can use some DataSet or something and use it like "SQL server".

Comment: @Default I fixed bad parentId.

Comment: @Kamil, no what I'm trying to say is: If there is no defined relationship between the parentId column and what level of the tree you're in (which is my guess), then you'll be hard pressed to find an efficient solution to this problem. If you're willing to spend the time making it efficient, I'd find an actual tree structure to port it to if you're unwilling or unable to use SQL. If not, something like Default's solution is your best bet if your data somehow displays what level of the tree it's in.

Comment: OK. Now I know everything. I will iterate over first level items to get their children items. I think it will be efficient enough for me. In addition - that may be more efficient than idea with determining level in tree, because I have 30k rows, but I need only about 200 and I can totally ignore rows where parentId does not belong to any first level item.

Comment: @Default please put an answer, so I can accept your suggestion with `foreach`.

Comment: Can you map your data rows to objects and instead querying the data table use linq queries?

Comment: @Ela Yes, I can use LINQ.

Comment: @Kamil than see my response, this gives you a solution which can give you all levels and you don't have to hardcode code for first/second lvl... More or less the equivalent to the recursive With... query trick in TSQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this helps:

```
var rows = table.AsEnumerable();
var parents = rows.Where(r => !r.Field<int?>("parentId").HasValue);
var children = rows.Where(r => r.Field<int?>("parentId").HasValue);
var secondLevel = from parent in parents
                  join child in children
                  on parent.Field<int>("id") equals child.Field<int?>("parentId").Value
                  select child;
var both = parents.Concat(secondLevel).CopyToDataTable();
```

Note that i've used   `Nullable<int>` instead of 0 for a parent  since that is more readable and less prone of errors. Here is your sample data:

```
var table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("parentId", typeof(int));
table.Rows.Add(1, "One", (int?)null);
table.Rows.Add(2, "OneA", 1);
table.Rows.Add(3, "OneB", 1);
table.Rows.Add(4, "Two", (int?)null);
table.Rows.Add(5, "TwoA", 4);
table.Rows.Add(6, "TwoB", 4);
table.Rows.Add(7, "TwoAA", 5);
table.Rows.Add(8, "TwoAB", 5);
```

Result:

```
1   One 
4   Two 
2   OneA    1
3   OneB    1
5   TwoA    4
6   TwoB    4
```

Since you want to stay with `0` instead of `int?`:

```
var parents = rows.Where(r =>  r.Field<int>("parentId") == 0);
var children = rows.Where(r => r.Field<int>("parentId") != 0);
var secondLevel = from parent in parents
                  join child in children
                  on parent.Field<int>("id") equals child.Field<int>("parentId")
                  select child;
```

Comment: Well, this is exactly what I asked for! But I have no nulls in parentId ("main" items have parentId = 0).

Comment: @Kamil: You can replace the nullable checks with `== 0`, but i would prefer null instead of 0 what could be a valid ID.

Comment: @Kamil: Note that i've edited my answer since i had a nasty typo, i've used rows instead of parents. Now it returns realyl only the parents and the second level children.

Comment: I saw that something is wrong. I will use 0 instead of null parentId, because data comes from very stable web service and I don't expect any errors in that data. Nullable int will mess up my code too much.

Comment: @Kamil: Edited my answer to provide also the `0` approach without nullables. Also noticed that my sample data was not yours(copy/paste typo).

Answer (score 2):

I think this function might help you figure out the level of tree of each entry so you can use it in your selection:

```
    public int level(DataTable dt, DataRow row)
    {
        int parentid = int.Parse(row[2].ToString());
        if (parentid == 0)
            return 1;
        else
            return 1 + level(dt, GetDataRow(dt,parentid ));
    }

    public DataRow GetDataRow(DataTable dt, int id)
    {
        foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
        {
            if (int.Parse(r[0].ToString()) == id) return r;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: @Kamil, this is essentially where I was headed. If you use recursion and a counter to grab the parent id, you should be able to get the level of each item. The problem with this is, it's likely to be MUCH slower than iteration because you'll have to do recursion on every element instead of looping through. I think this is on the right track, but I don't think it's what you want to use. Now, alternatively, IF you really don't have ANY way of determining which level of the tree you're in from the data aside from the parentId, this is probably your only solution.

Comment: @DrewCopenhaver Yea. When I saw this code - I realized that this will be very inefficient in my case (see last comment under question).

Comment: @AliBaghdadi +1 for useful code and idea, but I will not use it now.

Comment: @Kamil the iteration is useful in your case, but what if you need to change your mind later and want to select 3 levels for example?

Comment: @AliBaghdadi That doesn't matter. It will still be an inefficient solution. In this particular case, a loop will always be more efficient than recursion.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options to your problem. As proposed by @Ali, you could use recursion like this:

```
public int level(DataTable dt, DataRow row)
{
    int parentid = int.Parse(row[2].ToString());
    if (parentid == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return 1 + level(dt, GetDataRow(dt,parentid ));
}

public DataRow GetDataRow(DataTable dt, int id)
{
    foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
    {
        if (int.Parse(r[0].ToString()) == id) return r;
    }
    return null;
}
```

But the problem is that you'll end up iterating though every element and then using recursion on every iteration. If you have absolutely no data relationship between your columns and their level in the tree, besides a parentId, then this is your only solution.

On the other hand, if you do have a relationship, where you have name[level of tree] like Name[A] is tree level 1 and Name[AB] is tree level two with the right node, then iteration through each like:

```
    foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
    {
        //Pull out the element
        //Check the element's level
       //Add it to the result set if level <= 2
    }
```

I'd personally prefer to solve the problem by actually building a tree structure or using a SQL WHERE clause, but it's hard to justify the time on it. Depending on where you get this data from, you may also be able to add an additional column which tells you which level the node is in depending on where it's inserted. If it has a grandparent (i.e. two parent nodes) you don't include it in the result set.

Answer (score 1):

```
DataTable level1 = (from t in dtCategories.AsEnumerable()
                    where t.Field<int>("parentId") == 0
                    select t).CopyToDataTable();

DataTable level2 =(from t1 in dtCategories.AsEnumerable()
                        join t2 in dtCategories.AsEnumerable() 
                           on t1.Field<int>("id") equals t2.Field<int>("parentId")
                   where t1.Field<int>("parentId") == 0
                   select t2).CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it, this will give you a new object which contains the level and the row item itself. This will work for n number of levels...

```
        var nodes = table.AsEnumerable();

        //var nodes = new List<TreeNode>();

        var parentId = 0;
        var countLevel = 0;
        var allNods = new List<dynamic>();

        while (nodes.Any(p => p.Field<int>("parentId") == parentId))// && countLevel < 2) 
            // countlevel< 2 only to give you the first 2 levels only...
        {
            var nodesWithLevel = nodes.Where(p => p.Field<int>("parentId") == parentId)
                        .Select(p => new { Level = parentId, Node = p });

            allNods = allNods.Concat<dynamic>(nodesWithLevel).ToList();
            parentId++;
            countLevel++;
        }
```

The code currently expects that the root nodes have parentId = 0. Could be changed to null, too of cause...